# Animate Google Map (SupportMapFragement)

Tags: android, animation, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

I am using `GoogleMap API V2` in my application, now i want to animate the whole `map layout` using `Fade_IN` and `Fade_OUT` animations, but when i test my application it is only animating the map overlays i mean the buttons present on map surface but not the whole map.

If anyone know how to animate the whole map layout please help me, any help wpuld be appreciable.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```